# NUnit: how to run only tests that have specific property (priority or type)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I want to have the ability to selectively run the NUnit tests based on several criteria. In my case, the selection will be based on: Test Priority and/or Test Type.

The test class/method would look like that:

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  public class MathTests
  {
    [Test, Property("Priority", "Critical"), Property("Type", "Fully automatic")]
public void AdditionTest()
      { /* ... */ }

    [Test, Property("Priority", "High"), Property("Type", "Partly automatic")]
public void MultiplicationTest()
      { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

I want to run only the tests that have "Priority" = "Critical" AND "Type" = "Fully automatic".

Is it possible to implement such selection with the NUnit? I know it is possible to select tests belonging to specific "categories" for execution, but it is only 1 criterion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Nunit Console Manual](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.4):

> The following command runs only the tests in the BaseLine category:
>
> nunit-console myassembly.dll /include:Database
>
> **Multiple categories may be specified on either option, by using commas to separate them**.

So I would expect something like `nunit-console myassembly.dll /include:Priority,Critical` to do what you want (I havent tested it).

Comment: More generally, there are [Category Expressions](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5.10); I'm unsure if this is what is asked here...

Comment: It is almost that I wanted to implement. Small edit: I had to name the categories like below:
        [Test,
            Description("Add an admin console user under system admin account"),
            Category("FeatureId: Add_an_admin_console_user"),
            Category("RequirementId: N/A"),
            Category("Priority: Critical"),
            Category("Type: Automatic"),
            Category("ApplicableTo: Server"),
        ]